# win32api determine if file is opened

Tags: python, winapi

Using win32api, how can I determine if a file is opened?

There is an example program [WhoUses.exe](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/processesmodules/article.php/c2827/Examine-Information-on-Windows-NT-System-Level-Primitives.htm), but its written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an OS agnostic version:

```
try:
  file = open("thefile.txt", "r+")
except IOError:
  print "File is open!"
```

Edited to add that your question is a duplicate of [check if a file is open in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825994/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a pointer to the file:

```
if f.closed:
    print('file is closed')
```