# How to prevent opening an already open file using Python/tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

sorry if this a dumb question... but I'm new to learning Python and this is a homework question...

So I want to stop people from reopening an already loaded file using tkinter - and have an error dialog box pop up when they try to open the file.

So far I've got this:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

def open_file(self):
    openfiles=[]
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("allfiles","*.txt")])

    if filename not in openfiles:
        openfiles.append(filename)
        self._filename = filename
        functiontoloadfile(filename)

    else:
        messagebox.showerror(filename + "is already open")
```

Comment: is `open_file` inside of a class?

Comment: Yeah it is inside of a class - sorry i didn't mention that

Comment: what is your question? You've told us what you want and what you have, but not what problem you're having.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check if a file is open in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825994/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `open_files()` is a function not inside of a class, you can persist your `openfiles` list like so:

```
openfiles=[]
def open_file(self):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("allfiles","*.txt")])

    if filename not in openfiles:
        openfiles.append(filename)
        functiontoloadfile(filename)
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(filename + "is already open")
```

This will keep your `openfiles` list across multiple invocations of the `open_file` function. Of course, you will need to make sure you remove from that list when the file is closed which can become a bit oh a headache.

An even better approach might be one, where you detect which UI elements are displaying the file, and infer from the presence of those UI elements whether or not the file is open.

Answer (score 0):

In python if you try opening a file that is already open you can raise an error like this:

```
try:
    myfile = open("myfile.csv", "r+") # or "a+", whatever you need
except IOError:
    print "Is already open"
```