# Python: Effective way to find out if another application has a file open

Tags: python

I would like to find via Python script if an application has opened a file. I know there is a lot of proposition out there, but none seems to be doing excactly what I want. I have tried a lot of solutions. But still can't get behavior expected. Want I want is to raise an exception when a python script tries to open a file that is open by pdf reader. For example, if I opened a file with a pdf reader, and try to open/rename it via a Python script, it should raise an exception. I have tried multiple pieces of code:

```
try:
    myfile = open("myfile.csv", "r+") # or "a+", whatever you need
except IOError:
    print "Could not open file! Please close Excel!"

with myfile:
    do_stuff()
```

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6825994/6608257), I tested many scripts and none worked perfectly. When I rename pdf file, even when it is open the rename is accepter and at the end.

This makes me wonder is this is impossible or I am doing wrong.

Comment: I don't think there's any general way to do this. Only privileged users can tell what files are open by other users.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, there aren't many (any?) elegant solutions to this.  Here is a cross-platform method I've found to work (in most cases).

**Test if the lock file exists.**

#### On Windows:

You won't see this in Win Exploder, but if you run `os.listdir()` on the file's directory you should see a `~$myfile.xlsx` lock file.  The naming convention is standard (as far as I know) so you can test for the existence of this file; or better yet, do a regex search.

#### On Linux:

Similar to the Win solution, look for the lock or swap file, usually named something like `~lock.myfile.xlsx#` or `.myfile.txt.swp`.

**Sys Admins:**
Please feel free to edit this post if you feel appropriate.  These are just some simple findings I've stumbled across along the way.

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to call [`lsof`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) or it's equivalents, depending on the operating system:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

def is_file_open_any_process(path: str) -> bool:
    if sys.platform in ["linux", "darwin"]:
        fnull = open(os.devnull, "w") # to redirect output to devnull
        retcode  = subprocess.call(["lsof", path], stdout=fnull, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        if retcode == 0:
            return True
        return False
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"not implemented for sys.platform: {sys.platform}")
```