# Can 2 separate python scripts access the same module at exactly the same time?

Tags: python, module

I have a situation where 2 separate scripts are running timers and will execute a call to the same module method at exactly the same time (with different arguments of course).

Will this cause a problem?

Comment: It is dependant on what you are running but if both scripts are just calling a function and that function does not access global information then it should be fine.

Comment: @ZacTodd Well, its calling the __init__ function, aka a class, but its a class with just one method, __init__

Comment: In general, there is no problem with running something in two different places. The problems would only occur depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @ZacTodd it just opens and appends a new line to a file. Pretty quick

Comment: If you creating a new class each time then and running a function based on the information of that class then there will be no issues. But if you running from two scripts you will be creating two instances of the module so they won't interact.

Comment: If the write is just adding a new line at the end of the file there may be an issue as one script could have the file open and the other tries to write, which will cause an error.

Comment: @ZacTodd, thats exactly what I am worried about.

Comment: You could check if the file is open and if it is wait until it closed.

Comment: Good idea, not so trivial to actually make that work though

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825994/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-python