# Check if a file is still open in python

Tags: python, file, command

On a Windows OS, I use a python script that open an image in paint, using:

`os.system("start %s" % path)`

User suppose to edit the image, save the changes and close the file.

I wish the program will wait in a loop till the file is close, and then continue to run.

I tried:

```
time.sleep(5)
while True:
    try:
        myfile = open(path, "r+")
    except IOError:
        continue
    break
myfile.close()
```

It seems to break the loop also if I don't close the file.
time.sleep(5) is to make sure the file got open successfully, and we don't have some timing issues.

Instead of `myfile = open(path, "r+")` I tried to use `os.rename()`, as someone advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825994/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-python), but it does the opposite - stay in the loop even after I close the file.

It seems duplicate from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825994/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-python),  but the solution there fits only for Excel files and I couldn't find an answer that fulfill my wish.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain in detail what you are trying to achieve? Not sure to get what your problem really is and what you need.

Comment: I want my program to go through many images, run some code that check if an image is "valid" or not. In case it is not valid, I want it to open in "paint" program, user manually fix it, and close it. After he is done, the program will carry on, so it can open for the user a new invalid image to fix. I don't want to open them all, but to wait until the user finished to fix an image, before I open a new one to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you would prefer to use the context manager version:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    # do something with f
# f is closed now
```

This is closing the file automatically for you.

Edit:
It seems the OP wants to launch Windows paint with an image that has been (somehow) detected to need some user editing.
An alternative to achieve this would be: while looping through the images make a simple call to:

```
path_to_image = <image_file_path_here>
os.system(f'mspaint {path_to_image }')
```

this will open Paint with the desired image and the program will only continue execution once the Paint window is closed.

Comment: But it opens it in python.. not in a new window in "paint" program for to user to edit, am I correct?

Comment: After edit - simple, clean, and great solution that works just great :)