# How to check if a file's window is closed/open Python?

Tags: python, function, file

How can I check when a file window is closed? I tried this:

```
import time
import os

path = input()
os.startfile(request)

try:
    file_path = open(path, 'rb')
except Exception:
    done = True
    while done:
        if file_path.closed:
            done = False
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
```

So the file starts before I start checking if the file is closed. Then, I open the file again, and because its open already, an exception should pop up, where I'm looping until the file is closed. I don't know whether the indication I made is right or not.

Please help!!! I'm desperate!!!

Comment: You can open a file many times. But what do you mean by "file window"??

Comment: Check the answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825994/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-python

Comment: If you get an exception when calling `open()`, the variable is never assigned, so you can't refer to `file_path`.

Comment: What's a `file window`?

Comment: My bad. I mean a panel. When you click twice on a file and it opens up with the default program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `file_path` in the `except:` block, because the variable isn't assigned if `open()` raises an exception.

You should put the loop around the `try/except`, not inside the `except`.

```
while True:
    try:
        file_path = open(path, 'rb')
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

It will open the file only once, and if the file is already open it will use the already opened fie

```
import time

import os

path = 'bescom-17-apr.pdf'

try:
   with open(path, "r") as file:
       print("opened file")
except IOError:
   print("file not found")
```