# How to open a excel file in edit mode?

Tags: python, excel, operating-system

I have multiple excel files in a folder and I want to open them using `os` library in python. I am using a command to open the excel file but it sometimes opens it in the `read_only` format.
Command is:

```
os.startfile(path)
```

but it is open in the read_only mode and shows this message before opening it.
[image]

I want to open it in edit mode, can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

In order to open the file in edit mode, just specify it like this:

```py
os.startfile(filename, 'edit')     # Can specify 'edit' as the operation
```

Comment: I did that but still it is saying that 'file in use' , read_only mode

Comment: This is because you've already opened it, and it can only edit the file through one access. @Vesper

Comment: No, it is not open anywhere, but still, it is showing this message.

Comment: But this snippet I showed you, is working fine for me. @Vesper
Please Consider restarting your system, I think some process is using your file, which leads to throw the 'file in use' error, when you try to open it.

Comment: isn't there any way that program can check If there is a excel file already open somewhere then it will close it first then only it will open it?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using? @Vesper

Comment: well first I am copying the file from one directory to another directory using shutil.copyfile('Production_Cost_Model_Code/Sub_Inputs/Load_Profile.xlsx', workingFolder + '/Sub_Inputs/Load_Profile.xlsx')

Comment: then just simply opening it using os.startfile(workingFolder + '/Sub_Inputs/Buses.xlsx', 'edit')

Comment: Did you try to reboot your system? @Vesper

Comment: Use this answer to open the excel files which are not open @Vesper:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56788021/14159253

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the operation that you want to do with `startfile()` method.
For example, in this case you require 'edit', so: `startfile(path, 'edit')`

(https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile)

Comment: I did that but still it is saying that 'file in use' , read_only mode

Comment: Side note: You can remove the Python version from the docs url and it will redirect to the latest version. E.g. https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.startfile will redirect to https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile (notice the ``/3/`` in the second url) which will show the docs for 3.10.1 (which is the latest stable release currently). The 2.7 docs are somewhat outdated, unless the question is explicitely tagged as 2.7