# Let xlwings pause when Excel file is already opened by someone else

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

At work, we are all using the same server. When someone else is using an Excel file, another cannot.
I have written a Python file to make my work easier but I need to open an Excel file which is used often by others.
When I execute the Python file and someone else works in the Excel file I get the following error:

return self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(3174, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Er is een uitzondering opgetreden.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Kan geen toegang krijgen tot PythonTest.xlsm.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Translated: There occured an exception. Not able to excess PythonTest.xlsm.

I would like my Python script to try to open the Excel file but if someone else is using it waits an tries again to open it a couple of seconds later.

```
import xlwings
import time

excel_file = xlwings.Book("my_file_path")

# while excel_file is opened by other user:
#     time.sleep(5)
#     try again to open the Excel file
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: I think this answer can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6826099/14909621

Comment: Thank you Vitalizzare. This points me in the right direction indeed. Using the right search words makes a lot of difference. Thanks a lot :)